# Is there a way to add a new partitions to a existing topic in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka

im using the "kafka-node" module to interact with a kafka server and cant find a way to add partition to a existing topic for example from 4 to 5.

Answer (score 1):

Adding partition to existing topic is not possible using 'kafka-node' module. As per the comments in [GitHub page](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/1224), that API is not yet implemented.